Creating a software killswitch in order to stop a loop that is running too fast to stop from IDE in Micropython
I am having some trouble with a code that I've written in MicroPython, for a Raspberry Pi Pico. I don't have any hardware killswitch installed, so I want to do that from a software implementation since I can't press the STOP button from Thonny, as the loop is running way too fast. The only way I can stop the program is by disconnecting the Raspberry from my computer, then disconnecting the gyroscope then plugging it again. And since I have to tune some parameters, this action takes a lot of time. Do you think you could help me with a simple killswitch that can kill my program by pressing a key on my keyboard or something?
I tried to spam stop button but it still wouldn't work. This is the loop I'm fighting:
def main():
    #time.sleep(5)
    H_bridge.init_motor_data()
    mpu6050.configure_mpu()
    #adxl345.configure_adxl()
    get_offsets()
    
    general_timer.init_general_timer(pid_control)

    while True:
            pass 
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I don't think it's generally true that a fast loop in MicroPython would prevent and IDE from interrupting the program.  (If that were true, it would be trivial to add a 100 µs sleep in your loop to slow it down.)  There must be something unusual happening, like your program might be stuck in loop in some low-level I/O routine somewhere that prevents it from handling USB interrupts in the usual way.  You should try to fix this problem at its root, by making a [mcve] and figuring out what is really going on.

include sleep every hundred or so loops...
